# Why does sudo not work with curl?

Tags: sudo, curl

I ran a command to download something with `curl` –

`sudo curl roots.cx/get | sh`

– and it threw a permission denied error.  So I did `sudo curl` and I got the same error … why is that?

I was able to run the install command without `curl`, but I needed to `sudo`, so why does `curl` not work with `sudo`?

Comment: Can you show the full command ?

Comment: Are you sure the website was not returning the "permission denied" error, rather then Perl ?  What variant of Linux are you using and is SELinux running ?

Comment: @davidgo I'm using OS X for this...

Comment: @Ofiris `sudo curl roots.cx/get | sh`

Comment: @GiH Try adding a sudo after the pipe

Comment: @Ofiris Thanks that worked! Care to put an answer to the question for why?  I don't fully understand why the initial command doesn't work with sudo, but once it is piped it does... just to be clear to anyone who reads this it worked with `curl roots.cx/get | sudo sh`

Comment: @GiH , posted as an answer, will add details soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use sudo after the pipe:

```
curl roots.cx/get | sudo sh
```

the get script involves some installation, requires sudo to run.

Comment: Not working on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: @Ain in Super User, consider [the popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574635/38108) to _Redirect output to a file permission denied?_ (2013-05-15).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use:

```
sudo \curl roots.cx/get | sh
```